# Daily records of activities from time series dataset

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataset that has the following columns: 
enroll_id,user_id,time,event
I want to create a dataframe that will have daily features per enrolment_id based on the time and event. for example for each a enrollment_id,  it should have daily event records. 
enrollment_id,click_day1, view_d1, click_day2, view_day2... 
I tried to create dummy variables with the events column. then I grouped by enrollment_id and time then aggregate by sum.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a sample dataset.

Comment: Please, provide your code and data. Without them, your question is going to be closed. Thanks.